# yii dropDownList populated data dynamically with Javascript posting null values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, yii

How do I retrieve the value which is populating data dynamically with Javascript in `yii` framework?  When I post the data it's inserting the database as `null`

in view

```
<ul class="birthday">
    <li><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'otherdate',array());?></li>
    <li><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'othermonth',array());?></li>
    <li><?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'otheryear',array());?></li>
<script type="text/javascript">
    date_populate("EmailForm_otherdate", "EmailForm_othermonth", "EmailForm_otheryear");
</script>
</ul>
```

in controller

```
$model = new EmailForm;
if (isset($_POST['EmailForm'])) {
$model->attributes = $_POST['EmailForm'];
echo $model->otherdate; //value null
}
```

Comment: Where are you posting the data to the database? can you provide that code?

Comment: check out the first function here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.table, you may have to use getItemsToUpdate(); then loop $model to assign attributes 1 at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added 'otherdate', 'othermonth' and 'otheryear' to the rules of your model?

```
public function rules() 
{
    return array(
        array('otherdate, othermonth, otheryear', 'safe'),
    );
}
```